# How to remove all zeros from string's beginning?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which is beginning with zeros:

```
string s = "000045zxxcC648700";
```

How can I remove them so that string will look like:

```
string s = "45zxxcC648700";
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I would use [TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx)

```
string no_start_zeros = s.TrimStart('0');
```

Comment: Awesome didn't know that method.

Answer (score 20):

You can use [`.TrimStart()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=VS.71).aspx) like this:

```
s.TrimStart('0')
```

Example:

```
string s = "000045zxxcC648700";
s = s.TrimStart('0');
//s == "45zxxcC648700"
```

Answer (score 2):

by using

```
s.TrimStart("0".ToCharArray())
```

Comment: Why use the verbose `"0".ToCharArray()` when `'0'` will also suffice?