# Why is TrimStart not recognised in VisualStudio for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, trim

I whant to use TrimStart for my string value like this: [How to remove all zeros from string's beginning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723735/how-to-remove-all-zeros-from-strings-beginning)

But TrimStart syntax is not recognise in VisualStudio. How to corectly generate it?

my code:

```
string str = parameters.Internal;
string s = str;
string no_start_zeros = s.TrimStart('0');
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesnt recognise the TrimStart?

Comment: Underline it in read and says that TrimStart is not recognised. I realy do not know what is downvote for...

Comment: Show the code please.

Comment: what syntax you are using put that in your question.

Comment: At the top of your .CS file do you have: using system; the method is found in the system namespace, which is mscorlib.dll - you can also try referencing mscorlib.dll

Comment: Ryno Coetzee YESSS, thanks man! I would like to put your coment as useful, but I can't, please mark it as useful!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer, mark it as answered then. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your .CS file do you have: `using system;` the `string.TrimStart();` method is found in the system namespace, which is contained inside mscorlib.dll - you can also try referencing mscorlib.dll directly.

Answer (score 1):

TrimStart() function is used to Removes all leading occurrences of a set of characters specified in an array from the current String object.
when visual studio version you are using ? as far as I know trimStart() support in almost all version from 1.1 to 4.5
check out below snippet for more detail

```
        string szInput = "000YTHLKJH";
        string output = szInput.TrimStart('0');
```

//output will be : YTHLKJH

Hope it helps