# REGEX .NET - strip leading zeros

Tags: .net, regex, strip

As a non-coder & first time poster, I'd like to strip leading zeros from a string. I can see numerous examples on stack overflow but none that i can actually test via the REGEX Search & replace function on this website:

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html

In simple terms, can someone please advise what regex needs to go in the first field and what goes in the 'Replacement' field.
(see image with red circled fields)

The string i'm testing with is:

'001234546'

and the output needs to be:

'123456'

thanks in advance!

[Regex_strip leading zeros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3eKH.jpg)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723735/how-to-remove-all-zeros-from-strings-beginning

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$number =~ s/^0*(\d+)$/$1/;
```

---

C#

```
string strInput = "0001234";
strInput.TrimStart('0');
```

---

Java

```
mystring.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "")
```

---

JavaScript

```
myVar.replace(/\b0+/g, '')
```

Comment: thanks Ajay, what expression goes in what field at this website?    http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html

Comment: I want to test it at this site: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html

Comment: You can use javascript rejex here.

Comment: if you think @Andrew_m_b , i have given the right answer then please mark as solved.

Comment: i entered in the javascript: (/\b0+/g, '') at the site: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html but it returned no match?

Comment: suppose you have a number in javascript var myNumber = 0001; and wanted to use regex then you should do like var result = myNumber.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", ""); // and you will get the '1' in result variable. Got IT!!

Comment: Sorry I have no coding experience at all. I know a small amount SQL for database queries but that's it. The regex issue i have is not embedded in any code, the regex test provided at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html, is the only place i can test the 'Regular expression', the 'replacement' and the input string. Sorry i'm not following, as i realize you are trying your best to help!

Comment: No worries. you can give me your file code and guide me where to add regex i will do it for you.!!

Answer (score 0):

I found this REGEX and it seems to work:

REGEX:          ^0*(.+)$

Replacement:        $1

string '00123456' becomes '123456'

thanks for your help Ajay